# Команда using()

Tags: c#, c#-faq

```
using(var variable)
{

}
```

Правильно ли я понял, что данная конструкция создает область видимости(работы) переменной variable. И после закрытия скобки вызывает Dispose() переменной?

Comment: Переменная должна быть IDisposable и инициализироваться.

Comment: @free_ze, инициализироваться не обязана

Comment: [оператор using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: @Grundy error CS0210: You must provide an initializer in a fixed or using statement declaration

Comment: @Grundy Иначе область видимости не будет ограничиваться блоком

Comment: @free_ze, ага, не будет

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Правильно ли я понял, что данная конструкция создает область
>   видимости(работы) переменной variable.

Да. Если переменная объявлена (и проинициализирована) в блоке, то ее область видимости ограничена только блоком `using`.

Также возможно использовать блок `using` c уже объявленной и проинициализированной переменной. Для чего это может понадобиться, см. ниже.

> И после закрытия скобки вызывает Dispose() переменной?

Да. Такой участок:

```
using (var x = ...)
{
    x.Foo();
}
```

Преобразовывается компилятором в следующий код:

```
var x = ...;
try
{
    x.Foo();
}
finally
{
    if (x != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)x).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что инициализация находится вне блока `try`.

Соответственно, использование в `using` уже проинициализированной переменной является более компактным способом записи `try/finally` с вызовом `Dispose()`.