# C# Как освободить ресурсы из Picturebox?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, как правильно открывать файл в pictureBox и правильно закрывать его для перезаписывания файла.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Команда using()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627394/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0-using)

Comment: Судя по ответу проблема была связана не с PictureBox, а с кодом чтения файла. Чтобы не сбивать людей с толку нужно в таких вопросах приводить [МСВП](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("test.png", FileMode.Open))
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Comment: `PictureBox.Dispose`

Comment: Пометьте свой вариант как ответ